# Pyspark - can't launch Pyspark shell in windows

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark, pyspark, cmd

I am trying to launch Pyspark on windows:

```sh
set PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--name" "PySparkShell" "pyspark-shell" && python3
```

but I am getting this error:

> C:\apps\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class: line 96: CMD: bad
> array subscript

I tried to add this to my `.bashrc` file but it is not working.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: is changing `&&` to `^&^&` what you wanted? Or does the following do what you wanted instead: `set "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS=--name PySparkShell pyspark-shell && python3"` or even `set "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--name" "PySparkShell" "pyspark-shell" && python3"`

Comment: @Compo it's not working. I tried all of them. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I've only corrected what you posted and offered some alternatives. I have no idea how yoou are using that variable and cannot therefore explain to you what it should look like. Instead of trying to get a fix for part of another command line command, how about you [edit] your question and provide the rest of the information we need to assist you. That will include the content of any other scripts, and/or configuration options, and all of the debugging information, and output.

Comment: Are you using WSL? Because you seem to talk about Windows and Bash at the same time.

Comment: @EvensF yes, I am using WSL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Pyspark or WSL (and I don't have the time to setup an test environment to explore my ideas) but since it looks like you are trying to set an environment variable in Bash and run Python afterwards have you tried this?

```sh
PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--name PySparkShell pyspark-shell" python3
```

which will set the environment variable only for the execution of the Python interpreter.

Or you could also try this:

```sh
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--name PySparkShell pyspark-shell" && python3
```

Would that help you?